# Broken models imports in Django when specifying app verbose_name

Tags: python, django

I am trying to customize the applications names within my Django 1.7 project as indicated in the documentation here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/applications/#for-application-authors

I think I've done as stated, but now I can't import models from app to app, e.g.:

```
ImportError: No module named comune.models
```

I've structured my project so that the applications are located 1 level deeper in the directory tree, like this:

```
project_root
  ├── apps
  │   ├── allegato
  │   ├── calendario
  │   ├── cliente
  │   ├── commessa
  │   ├── comune
  │   ├── laboratorio
  │   ├── recapito
  │   ├── spedizione
  │   ├── strumento
  │   ├── taratura
  │   └── tecnico
  ├── locale
  ├── media
  ├── project
  │   ├── . . . (my project directory)
  ├── static
  └── templates
```

I guess this might be what's causing the problem, but my attempts of fixing it didn't get very far yet.

Here's what I'm planning to do for each app, I'm showing the specific case of an app called *"cliente"* (the only one I've modified so far):

**__init__.py**

```
default_app_config = 'apps.cliente.apps.ClienteConfig'
```

**apps.py**

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class ClienteConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'apps.cliente'
    verbose_name = "Clienti e prodotti cliente"
```

**traceback:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/seether/.virtualenvs/mytime/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/seether/.virtualenvs/mytime/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/seether/.virtualenvs/mytime/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 21, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/seether/.virtualenvs/mytime/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/home/seether/.virtualenvs/mytime/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 197, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/seether/Projects/mytime/apps/cliente/models.py", line 6, in <module>
    from apps.comune.models import Comune, Cap
ImportError: No module named comune.models
```

What's wrong here that I can't see?

Comment: Not nearly enough information. For some reason you've hidden the contents of the apps directory, which is the important part, and you haven't shown the code that's causing the error or the traceback.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I've added the requested info.

Comment: Do you have a blank `__init__.py` file in the apps dir?

Comment: @DanielRoseman yes I do. Everything was working fine within the project until I tried this renaming thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it seems that the suggested file name "apps.py" is somehow tricking this strange behaviour. Perhaps being my applications directory called "apps" as well (as suggested in [Two Scoops of Django](http://twoscoopspress.org/products/two-scoops-of-django-1-6)) generates confusion.

Simply renaming the *apps.py* file to *config.py* and fixing the *__init__.py* accordingly like this:

**__init__.py**

```
default_app_config = 'apps.cliente.config.ClienteConfig'
```

does the trick.